Animated film where young man (prince?) searches for the keys to magic gates?
I am looking for a film I watched when I was in primary school (so around 2004-2009).
I am pretty sure it was a foreign language film watched with subtitles, but as I was super young I cannot remember what language it was. (possibly french?)
It was a colour film, animated in a 2D style similar to the Road to El Dorado.
The main character was a young blonde man with blue eyes, who was possibly a prince, or friends with a prince? He was childhood friends with a boy his age with darker skin, and I remember colouring in a scene from the movie where they sat on a wall/in a tree together, surrounded by lots of leaves.
Later on in the movie, when the man has grown up, he goes on some kind of adventure/quest to find the keys to three gates in some kind of magical temple. However, the country where he is doing this has some kind of prejudice/superstition against people with blue eyes, so he has to pretend to be blind. He finds a guide, who is an old, stooped man with large glasses. I remember this old man says a line something like 'You are blind, but I have good eyesight; you are young and strong and I cannot walk so well."There is another prince (?) who may be the childhood friend, who has darker skin and is also looking for the keys to the gates. The blonde prince manages to find the keys where the other prince fails, because he uses senses other than that of sight. One gate is a magical wall of fire, so he finds the key to it by feeling for a warm tile. The next (not sure of order) produces a very strong smell, so he smells it out. The last one is surrounded by clashing swords, so he hears it.
Right at the end of the film, the old man takes off his glasses to reveal he also has blue eyes.That's all I can remember off the top of my head, let me know if there's any further suggestions!

The movie is Azur & Asmar (2016).
Azur & Asmar: The Princes' Quest (French: Azur et Asmar) is a 2006 French-Spanish-Belgium-Italian 3D CGI animated fairytale fantasy film written and directed by Michel Ocelot and animated at the Paris animation and visual effects studio Mac Guff Ligne.
From IMDB:

Azure is a blond boy with blue eyes, Asmar has dark hair and dark eyes. As kids, they fought and loved each other as brothers do. As grown ups, they mercilessly become rival in the quest for the djinn's fairy, in a medieval Maghreb, full of dangers, magic spells and wonders

From Wiki:

Once upon a time there were two children nursed by Jénane: Azur, a blond, blue-eyed son of a nobleman, and Asmar, the tan skinned and dark-eyed child of Jenane. The nurse tells them the story of the Djinn-fairy waiting to be released from her chamber by a good and heroic prince. 
Brought up together they are as close as brothers until the day Azur's father cruelly separates them, banishing the nurse and Asmar from his home and sending Azur away to the city to receive schooling from a personal tutor. 
Years later, Azur is haunted by memories of the legendary Djinn-fairy, and takes it upon himself to journey all the way to Asmar's homeland to seek it out. Now reunited, he finds that Jénane has since become a successful merchant, while Asmar is now a member of the Royal Guard. However, Asmar also longs to find the Djinn-fairy, and only one of the two youths can be successful in his quest.


this is exactly the film, thanks!
